# Route data to internet through a specified interface

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I have a main server (Centos 6.2) which serves as router/firewall and has virtual machines.
Virtual machines are in the network 10.0.0.0/8 and everyone else (there is DHCP server) is at 192.168.0.0/16.

I have two interfaces facing the internet, ppp0 with a variable IP and ppp1 with a static IP. What I need to do is to make all outgoing traffic from 10.0.0.0/8 go through ppp1 so the virtual machines will be seen as the static IP. Machines in 192.168.0.0/16 must be able to communicate directly to machines in 10.0.0.0/8.

...basically, make all traffic that is to go to internet, go through ppp1 if it originates from 10.0.0.0/8. Retaining the ability to the different networks to talk to each other.

I have tried several examples of source based routing with no luck, I end up with no access from the main server to the virtual machines. Nothing with iptables seems to work either.

My whole schema looks like:

```
Server:
    ppp0:  facing internet variable ip
    ppp1:  facing internet static ip
    vnet0: bridge with ips: 192.168.0.1, 10.0.0.1
        eth1:  facing the local network
        vnet1: interface to the first virtual server
        vnet2: interface to the second virtual server

Virtual server 1:
    eth0:  interface connected to main server, with ip: 10.0.0.10.


Virtual server 2:
    eth0:  interface connected to main server, with ip: 10.0.0.11.


Local Machine *: (All the computers of people working in the office)
    eth*:  interface connected to main server, with ip: 192.168.0.*.
```

The output of `ip route show` in the server is:

```
10.9.100.1 dev ppp1  proto kernel  scope link  src 190.196.26.245 
10.52.173.3 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 190.21.97.109 
192.168.0.0/24 dev vnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2  scope link  metric 1004 
169.254.0.0/16 dev vnet0  scope link  metric 1005 
10.0.0.0/8 dev vnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1 
default dev ppp0  scope link
```

The output of `ip link show` is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:5e:c2:af:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:78:7c:47:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:f1:df:69:5c:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 00:14:78:7c:47:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 3
    link/ppp 
8: ppp1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc pfifo_fast state    UNKNOWN qlen 3
    link/ppp 
9: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:00:54:f8:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN    qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:00:d0:14:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Have you tried policy based routing? http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/TOC.html

Comment: @NickW I have not and I am in an emergency, I cannot read all that. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, I can give you a few examples that might work for you, but you should take time to read through it sooner than later, as it can create some very odd problems if misconfigured..

Comment: @NickW I would appreciate it certainly. I hope you can help me. And sure I will have to eventually learn all that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the `iproute` package installed to do policy routing.

```
# create a new ip routing table entry
echo "66 static-ip" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# add the rule entry to have packets with source 10.0.0.0/8 routed through the 
# alternate "static-ip" routing table
ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/8 lookup static-ip
# add the routes to the "static-ip" table
ip route add default dev ppp1 table static-ip
ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 dev vnet0 table static-ip
ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev vnet0 table static-ip
```

This would be it basically, but you would need to figure out how to make the entries reboot-persistent (which would typically be done by placing them into a startup script and parametrizing them a little to suit your needs). Take a look at [this mailing list post](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2011-January/105072.html) for an example how it could be done in CentOS-style.

Note that using a bridged interface with two IP aliases is probably not what you want as you would not be able to filter traffic securely - the bridged connection always would pass traffic from one net segment to another, no matter how you configure your IP filters. You should use two separate interfaces connected to 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16 networks respectively (eth0 and eth2 in your configuration if you would not be using a bridge AFAICS). Also the APIPA network (169.254.0.0/16) should be removed from the routes - add `NOZEROCONF=yes` to `/etc/sysconfig/network` and restart networking (or the host).

Comment: What should I exactly put in `<static-gateway>`, `<internal-router>` and `<internal-int>`. The last I imagine should be the name of the interface to my network.

Comment: @user1598585 `<static-gateway>` would be the next hop at your public interface - as this is a point-to-point interface, you should be able to omit the `via <static-gateway>` entirely. `internal-router` would be the router with a route to 192.168.0.0/16 if not connected locally. Otherwise omit the `via <internal-router>` as well. `<internal-int>` indeed would be the interface pointing towards your internal network 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: I tried this but I lose access to my virtual machine 10.0.0.11. Maybe it is worth to note that I have vnet0, a bridge with two ips, 192.168.0.1 and 10.0.0.1.

Comment: @user1598585 this seems exotic at best. Care to post your current interface and routing setup (`ip route show`, `ip link show`) as an update to your question? It is incredibly hard to predict the outcome of route changes for non-.straightforward setups without further info

Comment: I have updated my question with the information you asked for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1598585 I've inadvertently omitted the `table static-ip` clause to the `ip route add` statements - I've updated the answer to correct it. Could you try adding the routes again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8466/discussion-between-syneticon-dj-and-user1598585)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this did exactly what I wanted to. You really saved an important part of my job. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for the question but could it be that you stopped replying once you saw that I picked your answer as the correct one? I really cannot think of another reason for you not to reply my last questions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do Policy Based Routing, something along these lines:

`echo 200 Static >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`
`ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/8 table Static`
`ip route add default via <ppp1 IP> dev ppp1 table Static`
`ip route flush cache`

This will route any traffic from 10.0.0.0 through ppp1, any other traffic should obey the regular routing rules. You may need to add a rule to tell the networks how to talk to one another, this should do what you asked though..

Some further reading, this is a very good introduction to the concepts: http://lartc.org/howto/